# Lazy Evaluation not so Lazy?

Tags: c#, lazy-evaluation

I've always heard C# uses lazy evaluation.  So for certain code like, `if (true || DoExpensiveOperation()` will return `true` without executing `DoExpensiveOperation()`.

On an interview test I saw the following questions,

```
static bool WriteIfTrue(bool argument)
{
    if (argument)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("argument is true!");
    }

    return argument;
}

static void Main()
{
    // 1              0                       0                 1
    WriteIfTrue((WriteIfTrue(false) & WriteIfTrue(true)) || WriteIfTrue(true));

    // 1               1                     0                      1
    WriteIfTrue((WriteIfTrue(true) || WriteIfTrue(false)) & WriteIfTrue(true));

    //  0                 0                  0                    0
    WriteIfTrue((WriteIfTrue(false) & WriteIfTrue(true)) & WriteIfTrue(false));

    // 1                1                      0                   1
    WriteIfTrue((WriteIfTrue(true) || WriteIfTrue(false)) & WriteIfTrue(true));
}
```

How many times would it print "argument is true!" to the screen?

I would say `7` is the correct answer.  Now if I stick into the compiler and run it, it prints it `10` times!  Where did lazy evaluation all go wrong?

Comment: Are those & or && operators?

Comment: That's not lazy evaluation, it's short-circuiting. Also, you are mixing the bit-wise operators (`&`) with the logical operators (`||`).

Answer (score 42, accepted):

> I've always heard C# uses lazy evaluation.

That's far too vague a comment for me to agree with. If you'd said that the `||` and `&&` operators in C# are short-circuiting, only evaluating the second operand if the overall result couldn't be determined just from the first operand, *then* I'd agree with it. Lazy evaluation is a more wide-ranging concept - for example, LINQ queries use lazy (or deferred) evaluation, not actually fetching any data until the result is used.

You're using the [`&` operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbf85k1c.aspx), which *isn't* short-circuiting:

> The & operator evaluates both operators regardless of the first one's value.

The [`&&` operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2a723cdk.aspx) *is* short-circuiting:

> The operation `x && y` corresponds to the operation `x & y` except that if `x` is false, `y` is not evaluated, because the result of the AND operation is false no matter what the value of `y` is.

Replace `&` with `&&` everywhere in your code, and you'll see "argument is true!" printed 8 times (not 7 - count your comments again).

Comment: Honestly can't remember now if it was an & or an && on the test.  Would explain the unexpected behaviour though when I tested it, thanks!