# c# OR operator, how to find out which option triggered

Tags: c#

So if I use OR statement like this:

```
if (option1 == true || option2 == true)
{
    Print("would like to print the option that triggered above");
}
```

How do I figure out which option out of these 2 has been triggered?

Thanks

Comment: just split into 2 statements? Or add another nested one

Comment: In debug mode, put a Break point and mouse over the `==`. Or Display both..

Comment: `if (option1 || option2) Print(option1 ? "1" : "2");`

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy is right, since in C# `||` and `&&` only evaluate the second (and following) options if the result cannot be determined by the first (previous) ones. See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/13107726/2137237 .

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry but you can't.

But instead you can split the if statement

```
if (option1 == true)
{
    Print("option1 is true");
}
if (option2 == true)
{
    Print("option2 is true");
}
```

or put additional checks inside of the if statement(but it's useless).

```
if(option1 == true || option2 == true){
    if (option1 == true)
    {
        Print("option1 is true");
    }
    if (option2 == true)
    {
        Print("option2 is true");
    }
}
```

also you can use

```
if(option1){}
```

instead of

```
if(option1 == true){}
```

oh, and you could also use this to check if both are true

```
if (option1 == true && option2 == true)
{
    Print("both options are true");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using `else if` condition.

E.g.:

```
    if(option1 && !option2)
    {
        //Option 1
    }else if(!option1 && option2)
    {
        //option 2
    }else if(option1 && option2)
    {
        //both
    }
    else
    {
        //no option
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (option1 == true || option2 == true)
{
    if(option1)
        Print("Option 1");
    else
        Print("Option2");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly get in dangerous water, though, as you might end up with a situation where `option1 == true` and `option2 == true`.

If you really need to know which one was triggered, I would suggest you branch out. `if(option1 == true) { ... } else if(option2 == true) { ... } else { ... }`.

You could also do this:

```
if(option1 == true || option2 == true) {
    if(option1 == true) {}
    if(option2 == true) {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to test them both again inside the if statement.

Note the short circuit 'or' statement you have used (||). So if option1 one is true, it wont test the second condition.

```
   if (option1 == true || option2 == true)
            {
                if (option1 == true)
                {
                    Print("option1");
                }
                else
                {
                    Print("option2");
                }              
            }
```

Comment: what if both options are true?

Comment: Added comment about short circuit.

Answer (score 0):

You can not find which statement is trigger in your code, you need 2 statements

```
if (option1 == true || option2 == true)// statement 1
{
    Print( option1  ?  "option 1 triggered above" : "option 2 triggered above");// statement 2
}
```